# PHP - Wordpress function Parse error

Tags: php, wordpress

So I am trying to add a shortcode in wordpress to let me display the default WP login form...with reference to the codex page on wp_login_form(); I made a few edits to this code so that it should redirect to the url specified...but I get a parse error and can't see what's wrong:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')'
```

Here is the code itself:

```
//Login form Shortcode
add_shortcode( 'login-form', 'my_login_form_shortcode' );
/**
 * Displays a login form.
 *
 * @since 0.1.0
 * @uses wp_login_form() Displays the login form.
 */
function my_login_form_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {

    $defaults = array('redirect'       => ( is_ssl() ? 'https://outrankd.com' : 'http://outrankd.com' ) . 

        extract(shortcode_atts($defaults, $atts));
        if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
        $content = wp_login_form( array( 'echo' => false, 'redirect' => $redirect ) );
        }
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: `array('redirect'` do not have closing `(` braces

Answer (score 0):

You did not correctly ended array. Change your code to:

```
//Login form Shortcode
add_shortcode('login-form', 'my_login_form_shortcode');
/**
 * Displays a login form.
 *
 * @since 0.1.0
 * @uses wp_login_form() Displays the login form.
 */
function my_login_form_shortcode($atts, $content = null) {

    $defaults = array('redirect' => (is_ssl() ? 'https://outrankd.com' : 'http://outrankd.com'));
    extract(shortcode_atts($defaults, $atts));
    if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
        $content = wp_login_form(array('echo' => false, 'redirect' => $redirect));
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that will give it a go

Comment: it gives this: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')'